# crash in laravel default serve

Tags: php, laravel, apache

I use the default web server on my laravel application (PHP artisan serve) and use it locally for 10 to 30 people usually application runs very well and doesn't have any exceptions or crashes, especially on the web server. In sometimes in especial setitution where I don't know what a bug is, one exception happens, and the web server stops Immediately.
Exception is:

> local.ERROR: Undefined array key 1 {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined array key 1 at C:\laragon\www\queueing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php:289)

Just in case here is stacktrace

```
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\laragon\\www\\queueing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions.php(259): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Undefined array...', 'C:\\\\laragon\\\\www\\\\...', 289)
#1 C:\\laragon\\www\\queueing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\ServeCommand.php(289): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\{closure}(2, 'Undefined array...', 'C:\\\\laragon\\\\www\\\\...', 289)
#2 C:\\laragon\\www\\queueing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\ServeCommand.php(239): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\ServeCommand->getDateFromLine('1:61077 Accepte...')
#3 C:\\laragon\\www\\queueing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Collections\\Traits\\EnumeratesValues.php(262): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\ServeCommand->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\{closure}('1:61077 Accepte...', 0)
#4 C:\\laragon\\www\\queueing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\ServeCommand.php(276): Illuminate\\Support\\Collection->each(Object(Closure))
#5 C:\\laragon\\www\\queueing\\vendor\\symfony\\process\\Process.php(1274): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\ServeCommand->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\{closure}('err', '1:61077 Accepte...')
#6 C:\\laragon\\www\\queueing\\vendor\\symfony\\process\\Process.php(1372): Symfony\\Component\\Process\\Process->Symfony\\Component\\Process\\{closure}('err', '1:61077 Accepte...')
#7 C:\\laragon\\www\\queueing\\vendor\\symfony\\process\\Process.php(1292): Symfony\\Component\\Process\\Process->readPipes(false, false)
#8 C:\\laragon\\www\\queueing\\vendor\\symfony\\process\\Process.php(836): Symfony\\Component\\Process\\Process->updateStatus(false)
#9 C:\\laragon\\www\\queueing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\ServeCommand.php(93): Symfony\\Component\\Process\\Process->isRunning()
#10 C:\\laragon\\www\\queueing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod.php(36): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\ServeCommand->handle()
#11 C:\\laragon\\www\\queueing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Util.php(41): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#12 C:\\laragon\\www\\queueing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#13 C:\\laragon\\www\\queueing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#14 C:\\laragon\\www\\queueing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(651): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#15 C:\\laragon\\www\\queueing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Console\\Command.php(144): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#16 C:\\laragon\\www\\queueing\\vendor\\symfony\\console\\Command\\Command.php(308): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#17 C:\\laragon\\www\\queueing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Console\\Command.php(126): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#18 C:\\laragon\\www\\queueing\\vendor\\symfony\\console\\Application.php(1002): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#19 C:\\laragon\\www\\queueing\\vendor\\symfony\\console\\Application.php(299): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\ServeCommand), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#20 C:\\laragon\\www\\queueing\\vendor\\symfony\\console\\Application.php(171): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#21 C:\\laragon\\www\\queueing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Console\\Application.php(102): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#22 C:\\laragon\\www\\queueing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#23 C:\\laragon\\www\\queueing\\artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#24 {main}
```

I have a deep look in my codes, and everything looks normal, don't have any infinite loop or everything like this. Also, I put every suspect function to try catch, but there is no record of any log from my try catches, so I would be grateful if you could help me.

Comment: That error is telling you that something is trying to access an element on an `array` with the key of `1` and that key doesn't exist. Have a look for instances where you're accessing `array` elements (either in loops or manually) and maybe update your code to protect against such things and/or write errors to a log file.

Comment: As a side note, the [built in PHP web server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) is really only supposed to be used for development and demonstration purposes. Not advisable to use it as a production server.

Comment: "everything looks normal" if i had a nickel. post your command code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as dear @Peppermintology told php built-in server can not handle many requests so I switched to Nginx and use supervisor and fix the problem was soled!